# Junit testing and ensuring that no unnecessary changes have been made to objects

Tags: java, junit

I was wondering if there is any 'standard' way to ensure that a method does not modify any of the objects that are passed as a parameter to it. Example:

```
public void addMoney(Money moneyToAdd) {
    if(this.getCurrency().equals(moneyToAdd.getCurrency()){
        this.setAmount(this.getAmount() + moneyToAdd.getAmount());
        moneyToAdd.setAmount(this.getAmount()); // This is wrong!
    } else {
        throw new MoneyException(“Cannot add money with different currencies”)
    }
}
```

This is obviously not the expected behavior, however I am uncertain how to go about unit testing for this sort of issue (not even sure that it is necessary). The following are the cases that I would normally write for this method.

```
@Before 
public void prepareObjects(){
    Money gbpMoney1 = New Money(1.0,”GBP”);
    Money gbpMoney2 = New Money(2.0,”GBP”);
    Money euroMoney = New Money(1.0,”EUR”);
}

@Test
public void addMoneyWithSameCurrencyTest(){
        gbpMoney1.add(gbpMoney2);
        assertEquals(“Final amount is wrong”,3.0,gbpMoney1.getAmount());
}

@Test(expected = MoneyException.class)
public void addMoneyWithDifferentCurrencyTest(){
        gbpMoney1.add(euroMoney);
}
```

I know I could potentially assert that the object is the same as it was before in each test method execution, but is that the best way to go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a mocking framework.

An example in EasyMock would be as follows:

```
@Test
public void thatMoneyAddedIsNotAltered(){
    Money mockMoney = EasyMock.createMock(Money.class);
    EasyMock.expect( mockMoney.getCurrency() ).andReturn( "EUR" );
    EasyMock.expect( mockMoney.getAmount() ).andReturn( 3.0 );
    EasyMock.replay(mockMoney);

    Money realMoney = new Money();
    realMoney.addMoney( mockMoney );

    EasyMock.verify( mockMoney );
}
```

Only expecting the `getAmount` and `getCurrency` methods means that when those methods are called, they will behave how you have expected them to. (i.e. returning EUR & 3.0) There is also an implicit expectation that these calls will only happen once.

The call to `EasyMock.verify()` will then ensure that no other methods have been called upon the mocks that you provide it, thus ensuring the functionality you have expected.

For more information on mocking frameworks within Java, see [this article](http://java.dzone.com/articles/the-concept-mocking)

There are many libraries in Java that provide mocking, such as: [EasyMock](http://easymock.org/), [Mockito](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/) and [JMock](http://jmock.org/)

Comment: Hadn't thought of using mock objects in this way. Thank you very much!

Comment: This is a great approach if you must deal with mutable objects -- however the superior approach is to make value objects immutable in the first place.